.HTML POST extension for custom post type - DRAFT - PREVIEW
I use this code to "convert" custom post type in /customtype/postname.html
function rewrite_rules( $rules ) {
    $new_rules = array();
    foreach ( get_post_types() as $t )
        $new_rules[ $t . '/([^/]+)\.html$' ] = 'index.php?post_type=' . $t . '&name=$matches[1]';
    return $new_rules + $rules;
}

add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'custom_post_permalink' ); // for cpt post_type_link (rather than post_link)
function custom_post_permalink ( $post_link ) {
    global $post;
    $type = get_post_type( $post->ID );
    return home_url( $type . '/' . $post->post_name . '.html' );
}

It works so well.
But !
If you create a DRAFT post and after put cursor on PREVIEW (in wp - admin)
You will see url like this : http://www.domain.com/customtype/.html?preview=true
How I can fix it ? That problem only with "PREVIEW" link.

Here is a simple solution, if post have DRAFT status - we show a "normal" do not rewrited "URL".
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'custom_post_permalink' ); // for cpt post_type_link (rather than post_link)
function custom_post_permalink ( $post_link ) {
    global $post;
    $type = get_post_type( $post->ID );
    $post_status = get_post_status( $post->ID ); //get POST STATUS
    if($post_status != "draft") {
        return home_url('PUT YOUR CUSTOM POST TYPE HERE/'.$post->post_name.'.html');
    } else {
        //if POST STATUS is DRAFT
        return home_url('?post_type=PUT YOUR CUSTOM POST TYPE HERE&p='.$post->ID.'&preview=true');
    }

}


Looks like a solid answer. What would really turn it up to eleven would be to use this as a teachable moment and explain how the code solves the problem. Keep up the good work.
